# Is it possible to selectively disable syntax highlighting rules?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, quote

The context :

- GNU Emacs 26.1
- working on Debian 10.3
- currently editing YAML files (Ansible code)

Here's how my code looks like :

[image]

As you can see, the syntax highlighting is puzzled by the odd number of single quotes in `it's difficult...` and applies color to everything until it reaches the next single "single quote".

Is there a way to instruct the syntax highlighting logic that "single single quotes" are ok in lines starting with `- name:` and refrain it from colouring everything until the next "single single quote" ?

**NB :** this is a purely cosmetics question, everything works fine, no error message, just the display pictured above.

**EDIT:** Thank you @Lindydancer and @wasamasa. The solutions / workarounds you suggest are way beyond my Emacs skills, so I think I'll have to live with this cosmetic issue. Not able to pick my "favorite" answer either, sorry.

BTW, while working on different topics, I tried [Spacemacs](https://www.spacemacs.org/) and realized it can highlight my YAML snippet without being puzzled by the single quotes :

[image: Spacemacs on the left, regular Emacs on the right]

May this help those investigating, and others searching for an alternative.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem on Emacs 28.0.50, with yaml-mode Package-Version: 20210508.1641. For me, a yaml file is highlighted like the example you show from spacemacs. If you've installed yaml-mode from Debian, it may be outdated. Emacs 26 is three years old now too. Upgrading your Emacs and installing yaml-mode from melpa might solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you'd try fixing the highlighting in the mode itself.  I am the maintainer of yaml-mode, if you have ideas how to do this without ending up writing a YAML parser, please let me know on its issue tracker.

One possible workaround for programming languages with comment syntax is to put a comment starter on the affected line, then a string terminator and optionally a comment ender (or none if it's a line comment).  That way syntax highlighting doesn't bleed beyond that line.  I'm afraid you can't do that with YAML though.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to override the syntax table for specific syntactic constructs by overriding the variable `syntax-propertize-function`. It should be bound to a function that set the `syntax-table` text property on the part of the buffer where the default syntax table should be overridden.

One way to do this it to use the support function `syntax-propertize-rules`.

In the following example `<` and `>` around words are treated as parentheses. (It's part of the test suite of my [faceup](https://github.com/Lindydancer/faceup) package.)

```
(defvar faceup-test-mode-syntax-table
  (make-syntax-table)
  "Syntax table for `faceup-test-mode'.")

(defvar faceup-test-font-lock-keywords
  '(("\\_<WARNING\\_>"
     (0 (progn
          (add-text-properties (match-beginning 0)
                               (match-end 0)
                               '(help-echo "Baloon tip: Fly smoothly!"))
          font-lock-warning-face))))
  "Highlight rules for `faceup-test-mode'.")

(defun faceup-test-syntax-propertize (start end)
  (goto-char start)
  (funcall
   (syntax-propertize-rules
    ("\\(<\\)\\([^<>\n]*\\)\\(>\\)"
     (1 "()  ")
     (3 ")(  ")))
   start end))

(defmacro faceup-test-define-prog-mode (mode name &rest args)
  "Define a major mode for a programming language.
If `prog-mode' is defined, inherit from it."
  (declare (indent defun))
  `(define-derived-mode
     ,mode ,(and (fboundp 'prog-mode) 'prog-mode)
     ,name ,@args))

(faceup-test-define-prog-mode faceup-test-mode "faceup-test"
  "Dummy major mode for testing `faceup', a test system for font-lock."
  (set (make-local-variable 'syntax-propertize-function)
       #'faceup-test-syntax-propertize)
  (setq font-lock-defaults '(faceup-test-font-lock-keywords nil)))
```